# Certificate Revocation with intermediate CAs - combine CRLs?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation, crl

I use Nginx for client-side authentication. 
Only the SSL-certificates from the User CA should have access to the application.

The CA hierarchy:

```
Root CA
    |
Intermediate CA
    |
User CA
```

So `ssl_verify_depth (maximum verification depth) =3`

Each CA has a CRL.

For Nginx I need one CRL document.

Do I need to combine the CRLs of Root CA, Intermediate CA and User CA?

Comment: you can't combine CRLs, it is not supported. Each CA issues its own CRL and chain validator downloads and examines CRLs for each CA separately.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Maybe _combine_ is the wrong word- you can **concatenate** multiple PEM-encoded CRLs into one file.[see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/565445/how-to-check-multiple-crl-lists-with-nginx-client-authentication)
If I only link to the crl of the User CA, would it be possible that someone with a certificate, which has been signed but since then revoked by the intermediate CA, has access to the server? 
(Since ssl_verify_depth is a maximum value, a verification depth of 2 could also be possible?)

Comment: What is the problem of using max depth = 3?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can concatenate the CRLs in PEM format.  I just worked this out on my own project and confirmed it works.

For example, something like this:

```
$ # Download the CRLs
$ wget http://example.org/root.crl
$ wget http://example.org/intermediate.crl
$ wget http://example.org/users.crl

$ # Convert to PEM format
$ openssl crl -in root.crl -out root.crl.pem
$ openssl crl -in intermediate.crl -out intermediate.crl.pem
$ openssl crl -in users.crl -out users.crl.pem

$ # Concatenate into single file:
$ cat root.crl.pem > combined.crl.pem
$ cat intermediate.crl.pem >> combined.crl.pem
$ cat users.crl.pem >> combined.crl.pem
```

And the nginx config

```
ssl_crl /path/to/combined.crl.pem;
```

In response to your comment on the question: for me, nginx refused to validate any client certificates until I combined all the CRLs so it could validate the entire chain against the CRLs.  So, no, you shouldn't have to worry about a revoked intermediate certificate getting access if you provide only the users CRL because no one will be able to get access until all the CRLs are provided to nginx.